# Migrating ASP.Net app to TypeScript Compile Errors

Tags: javascript, asp.net, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I have an existing, working ASP.NET SPA using lots of Javascript with VS2015.

I want to migrate to TypeScript, but i get tens of thousands of errors as every TypeScript issue is an error which then stops the build of the app.

This means I cannot build/debug or deploy using VSTS. I can disable the compilation on build, but that means i cant deploy using VSTS.

The errors are mostly because i use vanilla JS all over the place (inherited legacy app i am slowly converting to modern tech) to getElementById and Typescript wants me to cast these to a specific HTML...Element type to fix the missing property errors.

Yes I should and will fix the errors, but there are too many to fix straight away and they are just 'warning' type things as I know the JS works as its in production.

Is there any way to:

- Disable specific errors like these using something like a TSIGNORE directive?
- Convert these errors to warnings and then i can disable the 'warnings as errors' until i eventually fix them all
- Do something else to fix this

I want a seamless non-messing about experience in dev, debug and deploy to my Azure Web App so any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: doesn't the normal [show errors as warning](http://s6.postimg.org/kxzgjbmld/screenshot_344.png) help?

Comment: @balexandre No, thats the problem; all Typescript errors are reported as Errors and stops the build even if I turn off Treat All Warnings as Errors. With VS2015 project it seems any error stops the build.

Comment: Add a tsconfig.json and makes sure your TypeScript extension for VS is up to date. You can get the latest from https://typescriptlang.org

Comment: I have a tsconfig and the latest typescript version and extension